# Seguing from uicollectionview that is inside of a tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've put a uicollectionview inside of a uitableview. I'm having trouble seguing to another viewcontroller after selecting a collectionview cell that is inside of the table view cell.

```
// if the user selects a cell, navigate to the viewcontroller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // we check did cell exists or did we pressed a cell
    if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestingTableView

        // define index to later on pass exact guest user related info
        let index = cell2.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell)!.row

        print(index as Any)

        // if segue is guest...
        if segue.identifier == "guest" {

            // call guestvc to access guest var
            let guestvc = segue.destination as! GuestCommunityViewVC

            // assign guest user inf to guest var
            guestvc.guest = communities[index!] as! NSDictionary


        }

    }

}

}
```

I'm getting an error at the line:

```
let index = cell2.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell)!.row
```

because it is saying the value is nil. Does anyone know a better method to do this?

Comment: In the line above where you're getting the error, you're dequeuing a cell and down casting it as a TestingTableView object.  Did you mean to downcast this as a TableViewCell?

Comment: @bjd23 My collection view outlet is declared in the table view cell class because it is nested inside of the table view. This is the only way I can access the indexpath of the collectionview. However, i don't think it's even getting the indexpath of the collectionview if it's returning nil. I've been struggling with this for some time now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use a delegate, so when a UICollectionViewCell is pressed it sends this to the ViewController the UITableView is in?

Comment: I'm assuming you call performSegue method in your collectionView didSelectItemAt delegate method.  Can you use the indexPath obtained in that method and pass it to a property, i.e. selectedIndex, which you can later access in your prepare method?

Comment: @Jay can you please provide me with an example of how to do this? i'm not too experienced with swift

Comment: @bjd23 I cannot do this before I declared the variable selectedIndex, assigned the index selected in the didSelectItemAt however, the prepare method is ran before the selectedIndex is assigned so it returns nil

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 Not sure I follow.  If you declare an optional selectedIndex property in your view controller and then set it in the didSelectIemAt method and call performSegue, the prepare method will not be called until just before the segue occurs. If you implement like that, the prepare method cannot be called before selectedIndex is set.

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 ok added

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to use a delegate:

1) Create a protocol outside of a class declaration:

```
protocol customProtocolName:class {
      func pushToNewView(withData:[DataType])
}
```

note: use class in order to prevent a reference cycle

2) Create a delegate inside of the UITableViewCell that holds the reference to the UICollectionView:

```
class customUITableViewCell {
      weak var delegate:customProtocolName? = nil
}
```

3) Inside the UIViewController that holds the reference to the UITableView, make sure you add the protocol besides the class declaration and add the function we created to ensure that the protocol specifications are satisfied:

```
class customViewController: customProtocolName {
    func pushToNewView(withData:[DataType]) {
       //inside here is where you will write the code to trigger the segue to the desired new UIViewController
       //You can take this new data and store it in this ViewController and then during the segue pass it along
    }
}
```

4) In the UITableViewDelegate function, "cellForRowAt", set the delegate inside the customUITableViewCell to self:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! customUITableViewCell
         cell.delegate = self
     return cell
}
```

5) Inside the customUITableViewCell, where the UICollectionView delegate function handles "didSelectItemAt" delegate function, you trigger the protocol function there like so:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.pushToNewView(withData:[DataType])
}
```

This is a very simplified example, if you wanted to pass an IndexPath, then you can modify the function to do so. you can also pass back anything you want as well, it isn't limited.

Comment: but how do i transfer an array that is in the tableViewCell class with the segue to the next viewController

Comment: I modified my answer to show how you can pass data using the delegate, and then during the segue delegate function, you can pass the information to the next viewController. Try to ignore the naming conventions, it's a very trivial example, you'll need to modify it for you project. Also "DataType" is the interchangeable custom data object type, if you've created one, that you'll use.

Comment: So if I am triggering the segue using indexpath.row would I place [IndexPath] where DataType is?

Comment: Correct, if you're using the row to determine what data to pass during the segue, you would pass back either the row or the indexPath(if you had multiple sections).